# Insert after variations via WooCommerce hook/filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add an input to a WooCommerce product via hook/filter.

The place I'm trying to add it is on a single product page, after the variation select (so just after the Time option box).

[image]

I've probably spent hours trying to find hooks, but all the documentation I can find is really awful or non-existant.

So far I've tried the following:

- `woocommerce_booking_add_to_cart`
- `woocommerce_before_product_variation`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The hook you are probably looking for it `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button`

You can see it in the `templates/single/add-to-cart/single.php` (and in fact, every add to cart template for every product type).  Therefore I presume it is in a similar template in the bookings plugin.

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
```

To my knowledge there is no visual hook reference for WooCommerce, so my best suggestion when you are looking for hooks/filters is to use a decent text editor like Sublime Text or Notepad++ and open the entire WooCommerce (or relevant plugin... or ideally both) folder and then have the text editor search for some HTML markup (classes and IDs are especially useful) that is near to what you want to modify.

I knew about this hook already because I have already used it in my own plugins, but if I didn't I would have searched for something like "single_variation_wrap" or "variations_button" and would have found the right template and the hook nearby.